# Can you please explain what's going on in this code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
```

Please Can anyone please explain this code?

Comment: It mean that `pageNumber` will be assigned the value of `page`, but if `page` is `null`, it will be assigned the value of 1 - refer [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Comment: You probably want to know about ??, it is null coalescing operator, If the page is null it will return 1 else value of page, see this documentation, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx.

Comment: thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if page variable is assigned it will set pageNumber to that value or else if page is null it will set pageNumber to 1